# Netinstall PXE for Ubuntu 13.04 keeps rebooting

Tags: 13.04, initramfs, pxe, tftp, netinstall

When I try to perform a netinstall with the 13.04 kernel/initrd the PC keeps rebooting without installing anything.
The PC starts with PXE, downloads kernel from TFTP, downloads the initrd and immediately after reboots, without any error message or any pause time.

I can't even find any way to debug my configuration, because it restarts immediately without any feedback.

Any suggestion?

Anybody got this netinstall working?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the pxelinux.0 i was using was largely outdated, and couldn't boot properly.

Fortunately Ubuntu ships a good pxelinux.0 kernel at the address http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/

and those should be used to load the PXE system.

In addition I had problems with the configuration, but in that folder the Ubuntu team placed the whole configuration to boot the system, so I just copyied it and it started.